# Check if file exists in Rails public path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to check if a file exists in the public folder of my Rails app.  I have this:

```
if File.file?("#{Rails.public_path}/cars/music/#{name.to_s.parameterize}.mp3")
```

The problem is that Rails.public_path returns as `/app/public`?   My `public` directory is not inside the `app` directory therefore it can't find the file.

What's going on here?

Comment: Do you have any intializers or anything in your configuration that can be messing up the paths? This is not the normal behavior for `Rails.public_path` which should give you something like `<Pathname:/Users/someuser/some/path/project/public>`. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails.html#method-c-public_path

Comment: Also since it returns a pathname object you should be able to do: `Rails.public_path.join("cars", "music", "#{name.to_s.parameterize}.mp3")` instead of a long string.

Comment: @max Not as far as I know.  I've just run through the app and really can't see anything changing it.  Is there a way to find out?

Comment: @max . I do have webpacker installed.  Could that be doing it?

Comment: Start by checking that Rails.root gives you the expected value. If not you're probably going to have to try to find the culprit manually or if you can figure out something clever to grep

Comment: I'm not sure about webpacker. You could use `Rails.method(:public_path).source_location` to see if has been monkeypatched.

Comment: @max . This is the source location returned: `["/usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails.rb", 110]`

Comment: @max and `Rails.root` returns: `<Pathname:/app>`

Comment: That's really interesting. Rails.root should return the root path to your application. I'm kind of surprised that you can change it without the whole app going bonkers.

Comment: @max Yeh, it's really weird! I can't see where it's actually getting changed and for what reason?

Comment: @max . It must be becing changed really early.  If i output the contents of `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` all the paths in there that start with `Rails.root` all end up starting with `/app/app`.  I'm super confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `Rails.public_path` returns the full path to the public folder of your project.

If your project is in some plataform like heroku or docker, that path will start with the `/app` directory. So, when you say that `Rails.public_path` is returning `/app/public` the "/app" its not your project's /app folder.

So when you do something like `Rails.root.join('public','cars','music',"#{name.to_s.parameterize}.mp3")` it should return the path `/app/public/cars/music/song.mp3`.

Comment: Ah!!! This is exactly it!  Thanks!  So then, if i'm checking if a file exists I should use `Rails.root.join('public','cars','music',"#{name.to_s.parameterize}.mp3")` but when i'm actually linking to the file should I use that or just a simple string to `/cars/music....mp3` etc?  Is that correct?

Comment: Actually you can also use `Rails.root.join('public','cars','music',"#{name.to_s.parameterize}.mp3")` command for that, as it returns an `Pathname` value type. You can learn more about Pathnames [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html)

Comment: Hmmm, I tried that and the path it returned was the full path and when clicked, the .mp3 file could not be located. However if I removed the `/app/public` part it works fine.  This is the part when linking to the file in the resulting view.